# no such module SWXMLHash while building SourceKitten

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, sourcekit

I cloned [SourceKitten](https://github.com/jpsim/SourceKitten) from github and when I open the project in Xcode, I am not able to build

In class `Clang+SourceKitten.swift`, I am getting `No such module SWXMLHash`

I have tried running `swift build` and `make install` from command line, which works perfectly. But, I need to create my own custom command line tool (similar to sourcekitten) - for which I need to open project and should be able to build and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I needed to update the carthage and open xcworkspace and everything was fine.